# Function to concatenate rows of data with an additional source column in R (and tidyverse)

Tags: r, concatenation, tibble

I want to be able to take data that's in the same format but from different sources and concatenate the rows, but to keep track of the source of the data I'd like to also introduce a source column.

This seems routine enough that I thought I'd create a utility function to do it, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble1 = tribble(
  ~a, ~b,
  1,2,
  3,4
)

tibble2 = tribble(
  ~a, ~b,
  5,6
)

bind_rows_with_source <- function(...){
  out = tibble()
  for (newtibb in list(...)){
    out <- bind_rows(out, newtibb %>% mutate(source = deparse(substitute(newtibb))))
  }
  return(out)
}

bind_rows_with_source(tibble1,tibble2)
#source column just contains the string 'newtibb' on all rows
#I want it to contain tibble1 for the first two rows and tibble2 for the third:
#~a, ~b, ~source
# 1,  2, tibble1
# 3,  4, tibble1
# 5,  6, tibble2
```

Is there already a function that could achieve this?
Is there a better approach than the utility function I tried to create?
Is there a way to correct my approach?

Sincere thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done as:

```
bind_rows(list(tibble1=tibble1, tibble2=tibble2), .id='source')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  source      a     b
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 tibble1     1     2
2 tibble1     3     4
3 tibble2     5     6
```

---

If you refer not inputing names:

```
bind_rows_with_source <- function(..., .id = 'source'){
  bind_rows(setNames(list(...), as.character(substitute(...()))), .id = .id)
}

bind_rows_with_source(tibble1,tibble2)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  source      a     b
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 tibble1     1     2
2 tibble1     3     4
3 tibble2     5     6
```

Comment: Excellent! I just didn't realise that bind_rows had the .id functionality. That combined with the list approach is exactly what I need.

Comment: @logarithmnblues if this answers your question you can consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your function-signature to be with `...`, you can use

```
bind_rows_with_source <- function(...){
  tibbleNames <- as.character(unlist(as.list(match.call())[-1]))
  tibbleList <- setNames(lapply(tibbleNames,get),tibbleNames)
  sourceCol <- rep(tibbleNames,times=sapply(tibbleList,NROW))
  out <- do.call("rbind",tibbleList)
  out$source <- sourceCol
  return(out)
}
```

or if you can use `dplyr`

```
bind_rows_with_source <- function(...){
  tibbleNames <- as.character(unlist(as.list(match.call())[-1]))
  tibbleList <- setNames(lapply(tibbleNames,get),tibbleNames)
  dplyr::bind_rows(tibbleList, .id='source')
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really nice neat approach in order to avoid having to write out the list as inputs to bind_rows. (I'm guessing in the last line of the dplyr code is meant to use the tibble list rather than typing out the list?)

Answer (score 0):

We could use `lazyeval` package: An alternative approach to non-standard evaluation using formulas. Provides a full implementation of LISP style 'quasiquotation',making it easier to generate code with other code.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/lazyeval.pdf

```
library(lazyeval)
my_function <- function(df) {
  df <- df %>% mutate(ref = expr_label(df))
  return(df)
}

a <- my_function(tibble1)
b <- my_function(tibble2)
bind_rows(a, b)
```

Output:

```
      a     b ref      
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1     1     2 `tibble1`
2     3     4 `tibble1`
3     5     6 `tibble2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(tibble1, tibble2), idcol = 'source')
```